# New to R, not able to use floor_date command despite having lubridate installed

Tags: r, function, package

As indicated above, can't get the floor_date command to work. My code is the following:

```
new_data$month <- floor_date(new_data$datadate, "month")
```

To which I get the following error message:

Error in floor_date(new_data$datadate, "month") :  could not find function "floor_date".

Not sure what the issue is. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `library(lubridate)` first?

Comment: Adding to @r2evans comment.  To use something in a package, you first have to install the package on your machine with `install.packages(pkg_name)`.  You can then use the package-function combined syntax like so:  `lubridate::floor_date()` or you call `library(lubridate)` to "attach" all objects in that package and then simply `floor_date()`.

Comment: Ahhh, package was installed but I didn't realize you had to use the library command before using it. Thank you for the help!